# MySQL query updating depending on $_POST values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble thinking out a good way to update my query depending on user $_POST values. Basically I have user management search button, where site administrator can search for his sites users. In my example:

```
<div id="website_user_management_search_left">
<div id="website_user_management_search_left_leftside">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <p>Surname:</p>
    <p>Telephone:</p>
    <p>Group:</p>
    <p>Discount group:</p>
</div>
<div id="website_user_management_search_left_rightside">
    <input type="text" name="#" value="#" id="userSearch_name">
    <input type="text" name="#" value="#" id="userSearch_surname">
    <input type="text" name="#" value="#">
    <input type="text" name="#" value="#">
    <input type="text" name="#" value="#">
    <input type="submit" id="button_adminUserSearch" value="Search">
</div>
```

Then after pressing "Search" button AJAX sends request to retrieve results, but how can I handle this dynamic query?
For example - if user just presses "Search" query would look like:

```
mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM accounts");
```

For example - if user specifys $_POST["name"] value, query would look like:

```
mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name='".$_POST["name"]."'");
```

Problem is - how can I efficiently handle this kind of query? It would be dumb to check which values is "isSet" and then make tons of query cases.
I hope you understood my problem and can help out with it, because it`s kinda hard to explain it.

Comment: Yes, I am new to javascript overall, so I don`t really know right names to call things there.

Comment: I don't know if it is permitted to post external link here but this is the answer: http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/.

Comment: Thanks, but it`s not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like it :

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = null;
} else $name = $_POST['name'];
```

Then in your statement, your condition would be :

```
WHERE (name=:name OR :name is null)
```

If name isset, it will search for this name, else it will return true and query will not be affected

Comment: This is the PDO syntax, that's why

Comment: Could you please show me how would mysqli look like? And also if I have multiple $_POST variables, how can I handle that?

Comment: I guess you just change :name by $name with concatenation. For more variables, you just add `AND (column = :var OR :var is null)`, you can add as much var as you want to

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE'%".$_POST["name"]."%'");
```

But there are two little problems:
You don't have escaped your user input data with mysqli_escape_string() and:
You shouldn't do that. A better way would be to add a where clause only, if `name` POST data is set:

```
$where = '';
if ($_POST['name']) {
  $where = ' WHERE name = '".$name."'"';
}
mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM accounts" . $where);
```